# Express redisStore:- can i store session as Array instead of String?

Tags: session, express, redis

```
app.use(express.session({
  store: new RedisStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
    db: 0,
    pass: 'RedisPASS'
  }),
  secret: '1234567890QWERTY'
}));
```

The above establishes redisStore to hold session data. However the session value is something like:-

```
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"user":{"__v":1,"_id":"52946af6eee73dc84600000c","dateOfMembership":"2013-11-26T09:33:42.633Z","email":"sa@abc.in","name":"sa@abc.in","following":[],"followers":[],"answers":[],"questions":[{"questionId":"52946b06eee73dc846000010","_id":"52946b06eee73dc846000012"}]}
```

Which is a string. Can i manage to store the above  value of session as a Array instead?

Edit: I understand that I can access all variables thru req.session.user ... but i need to manipulate value directly for which at present i'm having to use regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a JSON string (that's how `RedisStore` has to store 'complex' objects in Redis):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(sessiondata);
obj.property = newvalue;
var modifiedsessiondata = JSON.stringify(obj);
```